# what does default constructor do when it's empty?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

I wonder if anyone could explain what the default ctor does after memory allocated, how it initializes the allocated memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know which languange you asked the question for, but I will try to answer anyway for C++ and Java

In C++, it :

- leaves the built-in types (`int`, `float`, pointers, etc.) to an uninitialized value
- calls the default constructor on class members

In Java, I think all class members are initialized to their default value (0 or NULL).

Comment: So it does something in Java? ;)

Comment: @cularis : right, I was halfway writing the answer for C++ when I saw your comment on the question, so I added Java on the way;). I corrected the answer

Comment: so what do i need it for? , why is it mandatory to have at least one, even empty constructor?

Comment: @choppyyo : If you do not write it, the compiler defines one for you (either in C++ or Java), so you have a way to create some instance of the object even if you did not write any constructor.

Comment: @Louen: Actually, in C++, the auto-generated default constructor does something: It default-initializes every member of non-primitive type.  For example, if you have a `std::string` member, it will get initialized using the `std::string()` default ctor.

Answer (score 7):

Default constructors invoke the default constructors of all non-static data members, except those of built-in types, which remain uninitialised.

`[2003: 12.1/5]`:

> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that
>   can be called without an argument. If there is no user-declared
>   constructor for class X, a default constructor is implicitly declared.

`[2003: 12.1/8]`:

> Default constructors are called implicitly to create class objects of
>   static or automatic storage duration (3.7.1, 3.7.2) defined without an
>   initializer (8.5).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc15cplr376.htm) (in C and C++ implementation).

Yes, implementation varies from language to language.