# why can't objects be created without a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

why does creation of an object needs a constructor?
Even if I don't define a constructor a default constructor is generated ..but why a constructor necessary?

Comment: To correctly initialize the object?

Comment: Writing a constructor is ensuring that a piece of code always gets executed when an object is created, without you having to make the call yourself each time (initializing stuff...)

Comment: Your outrage may come from a confusion of the *language* and the generated *code*. A constructor is an abstract language concept. It may or may not entail actual code generation.

Comment: Why should living beings get "borne?" Why do we need to create things in the real world? Why doesn't everything exist in the first place?

Comment: @Jaywalker I'm asking "why are 'we'(or someone) needed to create things?"

Answer (score 8):

> why can't objects be created without a constructor?

This is more of a discussion on terminology than a real argument about the behavior. As you mention, in some cases there is nothing to be done during construction, so there should be no need for a constructor, right? Well, there is the concept of a *trivial-constructor* which is a constructor that does not do anything at all. For the sake of the standard document, it is easier to treat everything as having a (possibly trivial) constructor than to have to provide all the cases and exceptions in all places where it currently just states 'constructor'.

Consider that every use of 'constructor' would have to be replaced by 'constructor or nothing if the type does not have any virtual functions or bases and no members that require the generation of a constructor'.

This is the same reason why all virtual functions are called *overrider* even the first one in the hierarchy that by definition does not *override* anything. This form of generalization makes the language slightly easier to interpret, although not too many people will claim that section 8.5 on initialization is simple...

Also note that, while all user defined types by definition have a constructor, the constructor is not *required* for the creation of objects. In particular for objects with *trivial-constructor* the lifetime starts when the memory for the object is allocated (the standard, knowing that *trivial* means nothing to be done does not even go through the hop of requiring that the constructor is run in that case.

---

3.8 [basic.life]/1

> The lifetime of an object is a runtime property of the object. An object is said to have non-trivial initialization if it is of a class or aggregate type and it or one of its members is initialized by a constructor other than a trivial default constructor. [ Note: initialization by a trivial copy/move constructor is non-trivial initialization. — end note ] The lifetime of an object of type T begins when:
>
> -- storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and
>
> -- if the object has non-trivial initialization, its initialization is complete.

That second bullet used to read (C++03): *if T is a class type with a non-trivial constructor (12.1), the constructor call has completed.* Which more clearly stated that the constructor need not be executed. But the new wording expresses the intent in basically the same way. Only if the object has *non-trivial initialization*, the initialization needs to complete. For objects with *trivial-constructor* (trivial initialization) allocating the storage creates the object. Where does it matter?

```
struct T { int x; }; // implicitly defined trivial-constructor
T *p = static_cast<T*>(malloc(sizeof *p));

// *p is alive at this point, no need to do
T *q;
{ void *tmp = malloc(sizeof T);
  q = new (tmp) T;              // call constructor
}
```

Comment: I'm just reading a book and its mentioned as 
"If there was no constructor, an implicit no-argument constructor is built into the program automatically by the compiler, and it’s this constructor that created the objects, even though we didn’t define it in the class. This no-argument constructor is called the default constructor. If it weren’t created automatically by the constructor, you wouldn’t be able to create objects of a class for which no constructor was defined."

Comment: @pasha0077, I want to make it clear that you can define your own constructor, and as long as it can be called with no arguments, it's a default constructor, so the term isn't reserved for the compiler-generated one, which the "*the* default constructor" in the text seems to imply. And the last part isn't completely true, since while most forms of creating an object call a constructor, not quite all of them do, and that's ok for certain types of classes, but terribly wrong for others. I wouldn't say it's particularly bad wording, though, since you shouldn't really be using those methods anyway.

Comment: could u give me some examples where constructors are not used in creating objects?
And also note: NOT even the 'the default constructor' should b generated by the compiler.

Comment: @pasha0077: Provided the quote from the standard(s) [C++11, C++03] which is better than an example *and* an example.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas...
I didn't get you

Comment: @pasha0077: What is it that is not clear? *didn't get you* does not help me addressing your concerns

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas
It was about the comment u made just before mine...and I didn't read your edited  version of answer at that time...
Anyways, I just need the '3.8 [basic.life]/1' to understand the answer to my question....
thnq

Answer (score 1):

In a way, this is a slightly philosophical question. You can think of a constructor as a subroutine that turns some uninitialized memory into an object. Or you can think of it as a language feature that makes initialization easier to follow, write, and understand. You could even answer the question circularly: why does creation of an object needs a constructor? Because that's what creation of an object *is*, in a sense. If you don't have a constructor, what you're creating isn't an object.

It may be that a particular constructor does nothing, but that's an implementation detail of that class. The fact that every class has a constructor means that the class *encapsulates* what initialization is necessary: to use the class safely, you don't need to know whether the constructor does anything. In fact, in the presence of inheritance, vtables, debug-tracking, and other compiler features, you might not even know whether the constructor does anything. (C++ complicates this slightly by calling some classes POD types, but the encapsulation holds as long as you don't need to know that something is of POD type.)

The invocation of a constructor defines the point at which an object is created. In terms of language semantics, when the constructor finishes, the constructed object exists: before that, the object does not exist, and it is an error to use it as if it did. This is why *construction order* (that is, the order that member object and base class sub-object constructors are called) is so important in C++ and similar languages: if your constructor can throw an exception, it's necessary to destroy exactly those objects that have been constructed.

To end up with a working program, the programmer, anyone who tries to understand the source code, the compiler and linker, the runtime library, and any other compilation tools, all need to have a shared idea of what the program means: the *semantics* of the program. Agreeing on the *lifetime* of an object—when the compiler can run extra code to help create it, and when you can safely use it—is actually a big part of this agreement. Constructors and destructors are part of defining this lifetime. Even if they happen to be empty sometimes, they provide a way for us to agree when an object is valid, thus making it easier (possible) to *specify* and *understand* the language.

Comment: I didn't get u...
I've got that constructors are necessary for creating objects from above and nothing about y.

Please keep it short and to the point

Comment: While I agree with the first paragraph, I cannot agree with the third one, although it might be some imprecision and ignoring PODs... The lifetime of an object starts after the invocation of the constructor *completes* only if the constructor is non-trivial. For objects with trivial constructors, the lifetime starts at the point where the memory is allocated. No constructor involved.

Comment: The OP didn't even understand the explanation as it stands. I *really* don't want to go into POD types as well. Most of the time, it makes sense to think of even primitive types as having default constructors, and that makes the use of ctor-style initialization easy to grasp in examples like `int x(3);`.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a simple class :

```
class Foo
{
    int bar;
}
```

What is the value of `bar` exactly? Maybe *you* don't care when your object gets its memory allocated, but the machine running your program needs to give it some value. That's what the constructor is for : initializing class members to some value.

Comment: Constructors don't allocate memory, so they *also* don't care.

Comment: A default constructor would leave that uninitialized. `malloc` would work fine with that class and it doesn't call constructors.

Comment: `class Foo { Foo();~Foo();int bar;}` and whats the value of bar now?!

Comment: so you're saying 'a variable defined in a class has to initialized' and it cannot be like a variable defined in 'main' function which can exist even if it not initialized

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is necessary to call the constructors on class members, except built-in types [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773723/what-does-default-constructor-do-when-its-empty)

Comment: This doesn't really explain anything. Why do the class members need constructors too?

Comment: @DanHulme, they may have explicit constructors that should be called

Comment: It is also needed for other reasons, for example to update the virtual table pointer in objects with polymorphic behavior (vtables not being mandated, are none the less the *de-facto* standard) or virtual bases.

Answer (score 0):

Parametrized Constructors can take arguments. For example:

```
class example
{
     int p, q;
   public:
     example();
     example(int a, int b);                         //parameterized constructor
};
example :: example()
{
}
example :: example(int a, int b)
{
     p = a;
     q = b;
}
```

When an object is declared in a parameterized constructor, the initial values have to be passed as arguments to the constructor function. The normal way of object declaration may not work. The constructors can be called explicitly or implicitly. The method of calling the constructor implicitly is also called the shorthand method.

```
example e = example(0, 50);                     //explicit call

example e(0, 50);                               //implicit call
```

This is particularly useful to provide initial values to the object. 
Also you will find important stuff on this page :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Comment: without any constructs (including default construct), objects cannot be created.
Are you aware of it?

Comment: @Pasha0077 : Yes. That is absolutely correct. The instantiation of every object is like a function call to the constructor. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The implicit vs. explicit part is wrong. Both of them use *direct-initialization* to create a temporary (case 1), or the object directly (case 2). In the first case *copy-initialization* is then used to initialize the object `e`. In both cases the call to the constructor is **explicit**.

Comment: @iluvthee07, See David's answer for an example of where that comment doesn't hold up.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas : I have taken the example from Wikipedia itself. Also all the books I have read say the same thing about the implicit explicit part. My point is that theoretically I can assure you that the data is accurate. Practically, it is an altogether different thing as you have greater experience compared to me in such matters.

Comment: @iluvthee07 David is right: both the examples you give are of *explicit* constructor invocations. `example e;` would have an *implicit* invocation.

Comment: @DanHulme : I accept the fact that he may be right. I am just saying that all resources I have referred to have given the implicit vs explicit definition for **parametrized constructors** the way it is shown in the example. What you are saying is correct for **default constructor**.

Comment: @pasha0077 : So am I.

Comment: @iluvthee07: The wikipedia article is about constructors in general, outside of the context of any particular language. It does not apply directly to C++ as the term "explicit" has specific meanings in C++. The explicit in the answer and my comment are different concepts. I believe that in the context of a language with a standard, you can make up words with any meaning, but those words that have precise definitions must be used with that meaning. (I am perfectly fine with people calling *member functions* by the name *method*, for example, as it does not introduce confusion)

Comment: @iluvthee07   about what you said, "The instantiation of every object is like a function call to the constructor."
This makes a lot of sense if its true.
Can anyone prove that this is what happens?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas : I understand and agree with you. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @pasha0077 : In the example mentioned in my answer, you can see that the default constructor contains no statements. I suggest you put a 'cout<<' statement there and remove the parametrized constructor and see what happens when you declare an object without passing parameters.

Comment: @pasha0077 : Also check out this site : http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/85-constructors/ It has been and continues to be very helpful to me.